# Unexpected heap corruption occurs in function with exception handling

Tags: c++, exception, heap-corruption

I am programming a directed graph in C++.  The graph node pointers in the adjacency lists of my graph nodes are corrupted if I initialize them with a certain function that uses exception handling, but the lists are not corrupted if I initialize them with a similar function that does not use exception handling.

My graph class has a function with this heading:

```cpp
bool directed_edge(const Key& parent, const Key& child) throw(std::invalid_argument);
```

...and another function with this heading:

```cpp
std::tuple<bool, bool, bool> add_directed_edge(const Key& parent, const Key& child);
```

`directed_edge` throws an exception if either `parent` or `child` is absent from the current graph.  `add_directed_edge` works by calling `directed_edge` and handles the exception by actually adding the nodes to the list and *then* connecting them with an edge.

If I use `directed_edge` to create my edges, there is no data corruption at all - the adjacency lists of the graph nodes contain the expected data.  However, if I use `add_directed_edge`, the data is corrupted.  This is strange since `add_directed_edge` isn't really doing much besides calling `directed_edge` and handling any potential errors that it might throw.  This leads me to believe that it has something to do with the exception handling inside the function, but I'm not perfectly certain.

Here is the implementation for both functions:

```cpp
template<typename Key>
bool graph<Key>::directed_edge(const Key& parent, const Key& child) throw(std::invalid_argument)
{
    node* parentItor = find_node(parent);
    node* childItor = find_node(child);

    // Return true if the edge was added
    return parentItor->directed_edge(childItor);
}

template<typename Key>
std::tuple<bool, bool, bool>
graph<Key>::add_directed_edge(const Key& parent, const Key& child)
{
    bool parentAdded;
    bool childAdded;
    bool edgeAdded;

    // Try to add the directed edge.  Exception thrown if either doesn't exist
    try {
        edgeAdded = directed_edge(parent, child);
        return std::make_tuple(false, false, edgeAdded);
    }
    catch(std::invalid_argument& invArg) {
        // Add parent and child, and assign to see if they needed to be added
        parentAdded = add(parent);
        childAdded = add(child);

        // Add the directed edge
        edgeAdded = directed_edge(parent, child);
        return std::make_tuple(parentAdded, childAdded, edgeAdded);
    }
}
```

I realize that both of these functions are calling a *lot* of other functions, so if you'd like to see more implementation details, you can comment and I should get back to you soon

I ran three tests with some basic data. In the first test, I manually added nodes 0-9, then used `directed_edge` to establish a few connections.  The result is this:

```
0 -> 1, 3
1 -> 2, 4, 6, 7
2 -> 3, 8, 9
3 -> 
4 -> 6, 7, 5
5 -> 
6 -> 7
7 -> 
8 -> 
9 ->
```

In the second test, I didn't manually add any nodes to the graph.  I repeatedly called `add_directed_edge` since that function is designed to add nodes each time it is given a key to a node that does not exist.  The result is this:

```
0 -> 284985109, 976560249
1 -> 1752440936, 116, 17504392, 7
3 -> 
2 -> 1768366181, 8, 9
4 -> 6, 7, 5
6 -> 7
7 -> 
8 -> 
9 -> 
5 ->
```

Also, just to be thorough, I did a *third* test where I manually added all of the nodes and then called `add_directed_edge` to establish connections on pre-existing nodes.  Interestingly, this produced the expected results:

```
0 -> 1, 3
1 -> 2, 4, 6, 7
2 -> 3, 8, 9
3 -> 
4 -> 6, 7, 5
5 -> 
6 -> 7
7 -> 
8 -> 
9 ->
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to run your code with something like [Valgrind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind) or the gcc/clang [address-sanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer), they are usually good ways of identifying the cause of problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

Your hypothesis that the problem is with the exception handling in `add_directed_edge` is well-guessed, but incorrect.  The actual problem is that adding the graph nodes is causing the vector of graph nodes in the graph to resize, invalidating the graph node pointers in the adjacency lists of each graph

The graph class has a member variable `vector<graph_node<Key>> nodes`, and each graph node has a member variable `vector<graph_node<Key>*> adjacencyList`.  Whenever you make a directed edge between two nodes, you do something like: `nodes[i].adjacencyList.push_back(&nodes[j])`.  This would make node `i` point to node `j`

This is a problem.  The reference `&nodes[j]` will be invalidated any time the vector `nodes` needs to resize, because during the resize the data of `nodes[j]` is copied to a completely different place in memory.

[This](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) webpage has more info about containers - you should carefully read the section with the header "Iterator invalidation".  See what I see?  For the vector, *all* iterators (i.e. all pointers) are invalidated if the internal array is resized.

If you insist on adjacency lists having *pointers* to nodes, you should use an STL container with more stable iterators, such as a list or a map